# Azure DevOps pull request forbid manipulation of required reviewers

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, azure-repos

Is there anyway in Azure DevOps to forbid people from adding/removing required reviewers when creating a Pull Request?

I have set up the policy "Automatically included reviewers" with a bunch of required reviewers.

But still anyone who create a PR can easily add someone else in the required reviewer list or remove anybody from the automatically included required reviewer.

I want anyone to create a PR but not add/remove any required reviewer.

Comment: I'm searching for the same thing. I doesn't make sense to set a required reviewers policy if anyone can simply remove them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible, and they don't seem to consider it a bug. See [this feedback item](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-Devops-required-reviewer-removable/1467052). I think it is ridiculous that they don't consider this a bug. When you set a branch policy stating: `Pull requests to this branch van only be completed when these reviewers have reviewed it`, only people having the permission `Bypass policies when completing pull requests` should be able to complete the pull request without adhering to the policies, which includes the required reviewers policy.

I've added [a new feedback item](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/anyone-can-remove-required-reviewers-from-pull-req/1622487) to stress this. Feel free to update this feedback item, however history tells me they will either acknowledge the issue and never fix it, or still deny it is a bug.

We probably will we have to learn to live with this bug

Answer (score 0):

If a required reviewer is added via *Automatically included reviewers*, the reviewer can't be removed:

[image: screenshot pull request reviewers added via Automatically included reviewers can't be removed]

For reviewers added manually or via the API there's no way to forbid it as far as I know.
The following feature requests implicitly confirms this:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Users-able-to-change-required-reviewer-t/1196519